# Flex 4 - creating pop-up without disabling background / drag image without mouseup trigger?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex3, flex4, flexbuilder

Sorry to bother you, but I was hoping you could help me.  We are currently building a new web site and have run into some issues with our programmer.  I am trying to do some research to see if we can find a way for my issue to be solved so that I can let my programmer know.

First issue:

Go here: http://tinyurl.com/276we3f
At the pop-up just enter some example text.

Now, when you hover over any text boxes on the left of the card, you will see that the text boxes become highlighted with a border.  If you click in a text box, a properties pop-up appears that allows you to change the font, color, alignment, etc.  When you click close, it will take you back to the product and will highlight the text.  I want the user to be able to click anywhere within a text box to type new text.  For example, in the bottom text box, where it says "join us to celebrate", the user should be able to click anywhere in that text to change the wording.  They might want it to say "join me to celebrate" instead of "join us to celebrate".  However, if they click next to the word "us" so that they can change it....the pop-up appears.

Is there a way to just have a pop-up appear to the side and not have the background grayed out and disabled?

Also, is there a way to be able to click anywhere in the text box to edit just certain words or letters?

Second and final question:
If you click on "Click to add photo", you will see a pop-up appear that allows you to upload an image, edit it, etc.  After uploading the image, I want the user to be able to move the image around with their mouse by dragging it and positioning it in the exact spot that they want it in.  We also have the arrows where they can click the up, down, left or right arrow in the image editor pop-up....but I would like for them to be able to drag the image with their mouse as well.  We know how to enable dragging of the image.  However, the problem occurs when the user releases the mouse button.  On the mouseup when the user is done dragging....the pop-up will appear since the pop-up is triggered by the release of the mouse button.

Does that make sense?

Sorry for the long message and THANKS SO MUCH for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part of your question, when showing the dialog box for the properties of the text area, you can pop it up as a non-modal window.  This means the properties dialog will show but will not lock out the rest of the UI, enabling the user to change the text however they like.  It also means the background does not blur/grey out.  To pop up a window in a non-modal state, call PopUpManager.createPopUp (or PopUpManager.addPopUp) with the third parameter (modal) set to false.

For the second issue, set a member variable such as "isDragging" to true when you detect that the user is dragging the image around.  Then on mouse up, only display the pop up if isDragging is false.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks!  I will see if we can get this to work.  It sounds promising!

Comment: Great, glad I could help.  If you found it useful, feel free to upvote my answer ;)

Comment: I will keep you posted once we try your solution out...thanks again

Comment: Wade - one more question for you (or anyone else) if you do not mind.  First of all...THANK YOU for your help!  You did it.

My question is: do you have any idea how we can let a user move the image around with their mouse within the image placeholder?  In other words, my programmer says that they cannot figure out a way to allow the user to drag the image around since the image gets resized to the placeholder size and there would not be any "room" for movement of the picture.  However, if you upload an image and click on the arrows in the photo editor, you can move the image around just fine.

Comment: So I am trying to find a way that the user can also drag the image with their mouse.  A great example of what I am looking for is found here: 
http://tinyurl.com/2c74b47
***When a pop-up appears, just click continue.  You do not have to complete that information in order to see the card.  Once you see the card, just click in the box where the photo goes and you will see their photo editor.  You can upload an image and then you can see how you can either move the image around with the arrows or with your mouse. You can only move the image around a certain amount which I like. It stops it

Comment: from letting you move the image out of the placeholder.  Any ideas on how to accomplish this?  Sorry for the tough question!!!

Comment: You would do that by wrapping your image container in another container, such as a Group or a Canvas.  You then set clipAndEnableScrolling to true and turn off the scrollbars.  Then capture the mouse down on the image and move the viewport for the wrapper around.  Good luck.

Comment: Awesome - we will give that a try.  I OWE YOU!!  You are the man!

Comment: We are using Imagemagick to convert the output from the flex editor to a PDF that is print quality. We want to take the image that the customer has customized and convert it to a high quality, print quality PDF. Do you know of a way where we could also convert the customer's customized product into an EPS file so that we could open it within Adobe CS3 (such as Adobe inDesign) so that we could make changes to the file before we print it?

If the customer's output has some sections where the alignment of the text does not look perfect, we would like to be able to fix it before we print it.

Comment: anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!